# WKWebView Hangs on local webpage load with certain web configuration.

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView that loads a local set of webpages using `WKWebViewConfiguration` to set the configuration for `@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"` to be true.

The request is set up with something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"testPage" withExtension:@"html" subdirectory:@"html/pages"];
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0f];
```

Then the request is sent using the following WKWebview method:

```
- (nullable WKNavigation *)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;
```

my problem is where the device has a current connection but there is no network traffic. The webview as an element on the screen will be added to the screen and the request will be made but the webview will show a white screen for about 50 seconds before displaying the local content.

Everything in the webview loads regardless of the network status as its loaded locally when there is no link conditioner set.

For example if the device is connected to wireless but the network link conditioner is set to 100% loss. The webview is created and the request is sent to load the local content triggering the hang of the load.

I had a thought that it might be the WKWebView trying to do some kind of validation in the background that requires a network transaction but I did some network profiling with instruments and also some timeline recording in the safari webview and I couldnt see anything that would cause it to hang.

The only reason I can think of it loading local content after 50 seconds or so is that its hit some sort of WKWebView timeout to load a network connection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I created a sample project based on the code you provided, set the network link conditioner to 100% loss (verified that Safari in the simulator had no internet connection), and was unable to reproduce this problem. Can you post code that reproduces the problem (as simple as possible, leaving out any irrelevant details)?

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort @paulvs ! Ill put together a better example now.

Comment: @paulvs So I stripped everything out into a barebones project and the problem no longer occurs. Im now thinking the problem has something to do with the actual web content itself. Ill post back here if I work out what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so for anyone else who stumbles across this I have found what I was doing wrong.

The issue was not actually the WKWebview or the web content itself it was how I was handling the completion of the webview loading.

in the method:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation{
```

I was listening for a completion of events by evaluating some JS like so:

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation
{

    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.body.innerHTML" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) 
    {
        if (result != nil) {
        [self doCertainNetworkEvent]; //here another method is called with a networking function inside of it. 
    }
        if(error) 
        {
            NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];

}
```

The completion block of course couldnt finish until the network function within the didFinishNavigation method call was finished (which it couldnt because there was no traffic.)